# How do I move one singular object in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been trying to move only one cube using user input, but when I try I move both cubes in unison, not one, which is my goal. How do I move one cube (using user input) instead of both at the same time? Thanks :^)

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Crash!')
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

x = 150
y = 300
width = 100
height = 60
scHeight = 600
scWidth = 800
vel = 0.5

running = True

while running:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < scHeight - height - vel:
        y += vel
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    plane = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    meteor = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 0), (700, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use individual positions for the cubes:

```py
x1, y1 = 150, 300
x2, y2 = 700, 300
```

So the position of each cube can be changed individually. e.g. one cube can be moved by the arrow key, while the other one can be moved by <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y2 > vel:
    y2 -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y2 < scHeight - height - vel:
    y2 += vel
if keys[pygame.K_w] and y1 > vel:
    y1 -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_s] and y1 < scHeight - height - vel:
    y1 += vel
```

Each object is id draw at is own position:

```py
plane = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x1, y1, width, height))
meteor = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 0), (x2, y2, width, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

PyGame just draws the shapes you want it to draw, at the coords you tell it.
So, if we look at both `pygame.draw.rect()` calls, we can see that both have `y` in them, so when you update the `y` value on user input, you "move" both rectangles.